# SQL SUM not working - so it seems

Tags: sql, nested, sum

Schema:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
  `pageId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `linkId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `whenUsed` datetime NOT NULL,
  `whenRendered` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `pageId` (`pageId`),
  KEY `linkId` (`linkId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `links` (`pageId`, `linkId`, `whenUsed`, `whenRendered`) VALUES
(1, 9, '2013-02-14 00:44:20', '2013-02-14 00:42:39'),
(1, 9, '2013-02-14 00:44:21', '2013-02-14 00:42:39'),
(1, 9, '2013-02-14 00:44:23', '2013-02-14 00:44:21'),
(1, 8, '2013-02-14 00:44:25', '2013-02-14 00:44:23'),
(1, 7, '2013-02-14 00:44:26', '2013-02-14 00:44:25'),
(1, 6, '2013-02-14 00:44:28', '2013-02-14 00:44:26'),
(1, 3, '2013-02-14 00:44:29', '2013-02-14 00:44:26'),
(1, 7, '2013-02-14 00:44:31', '2013-02-14 00:44:29'),
(1, 8, '2013-02-14 00:44:32', '2013-02-14 00:44:31'),
(1, 11, '2013-02-14 00:44:34', '2013-02-14 00:44:32');
```

Inner Query:

```
SELECT `linkId`, 
TIMEDIFF(`whenUsed`, `whenRendered`) AS 'URDiff', 
CONVERT(DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()), SIGNED) AS 'dateDiff',
CONVERT('dateDiff' = 0, UNSIGNED) AS 'usedToday',
CONVERT('dateDiff' < 8 AND 'dateDiff' > 0, UNSIGNED) AS 'usedThisWeek',
CONVERT('dateDiff' < 31 AND 'dateDiff' > 7, UNSIGNED) AS 'usedThisMonth', 
CONVERT('dateDiff' < 365 AND 'dateDiff' > 30, UNSIGNED) AS 'usedThisYear'
FROM `links` 
WHERE MINUTE('URDiff') < 15 AND HOUR('URDiff') = 0
AND `pageId` = '1'
) AS T
```

Results of inner query:

```
+--------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| linkId | URDiff   | dateDiff | usedToday | usedThisWeek | usedThisMonth | usedThisYear |
+--------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|      9 | 00:01:41 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|      9 | 00:01:42 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|      9 | 00:00:02 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|      8 | 00:00:02 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|      7 | 00:00:01 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|      6 | 00:00:02 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|      3 | 00:00:03 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|      7 | 00:00:02 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|      8 | 00:00:01 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
|     11 | 00:00:02 |        0 |         1 |            0 |             0 |            0 |
+--------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Outer Query:

```
SELECT 
`linkId`,
SUM('T.usedToday') AS 'countToday',
SUM('T.usedThisWeek') AS 'countThisWeek',
SUM('T.usedThisMonth') AS 'countThisMonth',
SUM('T.usedThisYear') AS 'countThisYear'
FROM
(
SELECT `linkId`, 
TIMEDIFF(`whenUsed`, `whenRendered`) AS 'URDiff', 
CONVERT(DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()), SIGNED) AS 'dateDiff',
CONVERT('dateDiff' = 0, UNSIGNED) AS 'usedToday',
CONVERT('dateDiff' < 8 AND 'dateDiff' > 0, UNSIGNED) AS 'usedThisWeek',
CONVERT('dateDiff' < 31 AND 'dateDiff' > 7, UNSIGNED) AS 'usedThisMonth', 
CONVERT('dateDiff' < 365 AND 'dateDiff' > 30, UNSIGNED) AS 'usedThisYear'
FROM `links` 
WHERE MINUTE('URDiff') < 15 AND HOUR('URDiff') = 0
AND `pageId` = '1'
) AS T
GROUP BY `linkId`
```

Outer query result:

```
+--------+------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
| linkId | countToday | countThisWeek | countThisMonth | countThisYear |
+--------+------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
|      3 |          0 |             0 |              0 |             0 |
|      6 |          0 |             0 |              0 |             0 |
|      7 |          0 |             0 |              0 |             0 |
|      8 |          0 |             0 |              0 |             0 |
|      9 |          0 |             0 |              0 |             0 |
|     11 |          0 |             0 |              0 |             0 |
+--------+------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Go figure?  I can clearly see from the inner results that there are 3 rows in the usedToday column that are 1 (and I have converted them to unsigned so they should SUM ok) for linkId 9.  Yet the countToday for linkId 9 is 0 and not 3.  Why?

MySQL gives me some interesting warnings:

```
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect time value: 'URDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect time value: 'URDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'dateDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'dateDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'dateDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'dateDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'dateDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'dateDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'dateDiff'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedToday'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisWeek'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisMonth'
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T.usedThisYear'
```

From what I have been able to find online about this warning, it appears to happen for some people who didn't use quotes on their names (which I use everywhere).  Now why would a parser give such a warning for quote usage?

Comment: Try without the quotes `SUM(T.usedToday) AS 'countToday',`

Comment: My son just pointed out that using quotes in the column names and referencing aliases in other than the ORDER BY, HAVING or GROUP BY clauses was my problem.

Comment: The corrected query is: ... too long to post as a comment and I can't answer this question for 7 more hours!

Comment: Hope this helps others at least.

Answer (score 2):

Dad! Here's the query that worked:

```
SELECT
`linkId`,
SUM(T.usedToday)ascountToday,
SUM(T.usedThisWeek)as countThisWeek,
SUM(T.usedThisMonth)as countThisMonth,
SUM(T.usedThisYear)as countThisYear
FROM

(
    SELECT `linkId`,
    TIMEDIFF(`whenUsed`, `whenRendered`) as URDiff,
    DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) as `dateDiff`,
    if(DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) = 0, 1, 0)as usedToday,
    if(DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) < 8 AND DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) > 0, 1, 0)as usedThisWeek,
    if(DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) < 31 AND DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) > 7, 1, 0) as usedThisMonth,
    if(DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) < 365 AND DATEDIFF(`whenUsed`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) > 30, 1, 0) as usedThisYear
    FROM `links`
    WHERE MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(`whenUsed`, `whenRendered`)) < 15 AND HOUR(TIMEDIFF(`whenUsed`, `whenRendered`)) = 0
    AND `pageId` = 1
) as T

GROUP BY `linkId`
```